# How to check whether there is text in text field and button is clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield

I have app I want that if there is no any data in `textfield` and a button is not clicked yet, then it shows an alert view. Otherwise, it calls a method. I have `BOOL isClicked` and I have set to `YES` when button is clicked but how to check this and `textfield`.

```
BOOL isClicked;
feedbackTextfield; 
if(isClicked && feedbackTexfield)
```

Comment: if(yourTextField.text.length == 0) for checking whether text is there or not

Comment: What's your actual purpose ?

Comment: i want that when text is zero and BOOL is false then it show alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code....

```
  if((!isCliked) && ([feedbackTexfield.text length] == 0))
    {
        //button may not clicked or feedbackTextfield not contains text block.

        //Display your alert stuff

         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Button is not clicked" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
              [alertView show];  
    }
    else
    {
        //button may clicked or feedbackTextfield contains text block.
    }
```

This is solve your problem...

Comment: it is workin fine only for text condion BOOL is false still it is not showing alert

Comment: can you help me out please

Comment: insted of && we will use || then it will work fine please edit it i am accepting your answer

Comment: " if there is no any data in textfield and button is not clicked then it show alert" this is the requirement you posted, according to that i have framed the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(yourTextField.text.length == 0 && isClicked == FALSE)
{
   // Here goes Alert
}
else
{
  // Write your stuff
}
```